# How can I create following (link in description) pivot table in PowerBI / Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerbi, etl, powerpivot

I have data in following format, there are thousands of records in the same format.

[Actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfAHj.png)

and I want to transform the above data like this

[Expected Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMSZU.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far / where are you stuck? 
I'd recommend googling for some pivot table tutorials

Comment: There are 3 categories (Changed | NotChanged | NotReviewed) in the data and I want to use those categories as columns in Transformed table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your data
2. Insert tab - Pivot Table
3. Check the selected range and press ok.
4. More over drag or drop from the upper square box (includes all your available columns) to the 4 fields( Filters, Columns, Rows & Values) until you get the result you want.